# program returns sql syntax error, needed help in identifying the error

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm trying to build a search function using a textbox on a webform gridview which populates records from a remote mysql database. 
I'm stuck with the syntax error, however when I check the manual, and try to follow the correct syntax, the error persist. 
I'm using Asp.net 2013 with a remote mysql database.

```
public partial class resitDB : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string myConn = "SERVER=110.4.**.***;PORT=****;DATABASE= ***** ;UID=**** ;PASSWORD=***** ;";
    DataTable dt;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = Session["username"].ToString();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConn))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `tblresit`", conn))
                {
                    using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        com.Connection = conn;
                        da.SelectCommand = com;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            da.Fill(dt);
                            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                            GridView1.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //here

        searchData("");
    }

    public void searchData(string valueSearch)
    {
       //the sql error is here
        string query = "SELECT * FROM 'tblresit' WHERE CONCAT ('custName','IdResit','resitId','custId') LIKE '%"+valueSearch+"%' )";

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(myConn);
        MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(query, con);

        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(com);
        dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    protected void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string valueSearch = searchTxt.Text.ToString();
        searchData(valueSearch);
    }  
}
```

Comment: @Izzy, backticks are the MySQL equivalent of the SQL Server [ and ], unless that's changed since the last time I used it?

Comment: You have used normal quotes around the table name instead of backticks like in the first query. But let me ask. What are you trying to do with that concat around 4 literal string values?

Comment: @Steve I'm trying to use a search filter textbox which accept any key words from all four columns. I use the CONCAT keyword as it was referred by Mysql manual. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want to write something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblresit
WHERE custName LIKE '%valueSearch%' 
   or IdResit  LIKE '%valueSearch%'
   or resitId  LIKE '%valueSearch%'
   or custId   LIKE '%valueSearch%'
```

Comment: You should use `MySQLParameter` instead of concartenate string - `valueSearch` is from a Textbox and could also contain `'; DROP TABLE tblresit; `

Comment: I agree, but it wasn't about code review, just syntax troubles.  I think the question code has a lot of refactoring potential :-)

Comment: @less I used your syntax, but it still returns errors in sql syntax. I've also modified your code using MySQLParameter as stated by Toshi, but the problem still persist. Do you have any other alternatives to solving this problem. i just wanted to create a search filter for a gridview